# Find directories not containing subdirectories with today file date

Tags: centos, bash, find

Can you please help me with a bash string for finding and listing only **parent** directories **NOT** containing subdirectories with today file date, so i can delete them recursively?

My Env is CentOS and dir structure like this:

path='/data/mesos/slaves/somedir/frameworks/somedir/executors/'
this path is include 3 subdir
-appname
-runs
-onemoresubdir (here i need to search files with new date)

Thanks in advance for help!